# Find the general solution of a second-order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

The tactic I know can't solve this equation. So I tried to browsed similar ODE questions to find a solution.
I tried to follow this
[Solving a second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296534/solving-a-second-order-nonlinear-ordinary-differential-equation)

\begin{array}{l}
yy''+y^{\prime 2} =x\\
\frac{yy''-y^{\prime 2}}{y^{2}} +\frac{2y^{\prime 2}}{y^{2}} =\frac{x}{y^{2}}\\
\frac{yy''-y^{\prime 2}}{y^{2}} =\frac{x}{y^{2}} -\frac{2y^{\prime 2}}{y^{2}}\\
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right) =\frac{x}{y^{2}} -\frac{2y^{\prime 2}}{y^{2}}
\end{array}

But there is a problem in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296534/solving-a-second-order-nonlinear-ordinary-differential-equation). why $\frac{y}{y'}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right) =\frac{d}{dx}\left( log\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)\right)$ ? (It is not related to the subject, so there is no need to answer it.) Besides, it seems to fail to solve it.

Please let me know how to solve it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For the first question, note that $$yy'' + y'^{2} = (yy')' = \left(\frac{1}{2} y^{2} \right)'' $$ For your second question, you have $$(\ln z)' = \frac{z'}{z}$$ now let $z = y'/y \implies z' = y''/y - y'^{2}/y^{2}$ and simplify to see what the result should be.

Comment: As for a general solution of $y''=f(y',y,x)$, I doubt there is any such thing.

Comment: @MatthewCassell  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for your reminder. I will edit the title.